# Client user authentication or MAC address restriction possibilities for my web application

Tags: php, security, authentication, ssl-certificate

I have a php based web application involving some database. It has a username and password but the it can be shared with others. I have minimized the risk of it by blocking the ipsusing .htaccess (As below) except my office ip but inside the office still people can access it since its a shared ip.

```
 # ALLOW USER BY IP
<Limit GET POST>
 order deny,allow
 deny from all
 allow from 2.59.42.32
</Limit>

# PREVENT VIEWING OF .HTACCESS
<Files .htaccess>
 order allow,deny
 deny from all
</Files>
```

besides this, when the ip changes, i have to modify .htaccess which is a headache always.

Possible solutions in my mind:
1. I have heard about client certification in [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3605/certificate-based-authentication-vs-username-and-password-authentication) link but not sure how can i use it
2. Thinking about some way to restrict the web to only one MAC address which is my employees computer

What do you guys suggest?

Answer (score 1):

You wont be able to do a MAC authentification serverside, sadly.

How about a simple Username/password authentication from the htaccess through .htpasswd ? No need to make it anymore complex than neccesary. Just remember a strong password.

Comment: I have a user and pass authentication already. The problem is that the employees may share 'that' password with some else to misuse the data. Does the .htpasswd solves this prob?

Comment: Sadly not. There will always be the risk of sharing the login credentials. Just like a certificate could possibly be tampered.  
A combination of login and ip blocking seems like a logical way to go. Just too bad there is ip-changes :)

Comment: is it possible to install a certificate on that computer which i want to give access to. OThers wont be able to login with that passwords since the certificate will be missing in their computers..

Comment: Basically, yes. It's kinda a greyzone and from my experience pretty hard to acomplish. You could start here http://wiki.cacert.org/ApacheServerClientCertificateAuthentication

Comment: Oh. Actually just found this: http://it.toolbox.com/blogs/securitymonkey/howto-securing-a-website-with-client-ssl-certificates-11500 Might be of help to you! Cheers.

Comment: I came accross these certificates from the host provider. Do u suggest me getting one for the mentioned purpose?